# Improving RegExp Answers

Tags: discussion, answers

Is there anything we can do (besides meticulously comment and downvote) to improve answers to regular expression questions? Let's be honest.. they are terrible quality.

"How can I blah blah blah?"

"Oh, try this regular expression `\s\g+\$`" (<-- not a real regexp)

This is THE MOST COMMON answer I see that involves regex, and it's bad because nobody ever ever ever explains what the actual expression does, and it's very frustrating to see it over and over.

Comment: Yes, I noticed you preaching in the desert under a regex question a few minutes ago. I feel your pain.

Comment: How do you improve an answer to a terrible question?

Comment: @RobertHarvey explaining how the expression works would be a start, but I see your point. :P

Comment: I think what Robert might be saying is along the lines of: Why waste time on an explanation when most regex questions are people asking for something they can copy-paste without understanding (and often because they don't know the basic functionality of their host language that already solves their problem).

Comment: @PeterBoughton As someone that only knows bits of RegEx, it would be nice if the posters answered with how it works rather than "This should work: `some RegEx`".  Yeah, I'll ask RegEx questions occasionally, but that's out of a lack of understanding, not a lack of wanting to learn.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica the problem is that you don't get much thanks for spending time answering these kinds of questions because while you're carefully crafting your explanation, someone has already answered in a couple of lines. I daresay that there are far fewer wanting to learn than interested in a 2 minute turnaround on any regex problem.

Comment: @TomFenech I can understand the lack of gratuity bothering people who answer, I'm just saying not all RegEx askers want single-line answers.  Ideally we'd like to stop bothering the SO community for semi-complex RegEx! X'D

Comment: @Robert I'd say an improvement would not be to answer at all, or to add a reasonable level of detail to your explanation. At least then, the answer may serve a purpose to someone in the future.

Comment: Dropped.on.Caprica: **if a question specifically requests an explanation** of how to solve a problem with regex (or better: why an attempted solution doesn't work), then **it should receive one** - if it just receives the quick-fire one-line partial answers then downvote those and repeat the request for explanation/understanding in a comment on that answer.

Comment: I'm always happy to help people who want to learn regex, but I've pretty much stopped bothering with it on SO because I've wasted too much effort on people that don't care, and it's frustrating being halfway through a real answer when a one-liner with link gets accepted because it appears to solve what was asked for (but not necessarily what they need), and the OP has already moved on. **People that care unfortunately need to demonstrate they want a proper answer.**

Comment: Just for the record. I understood this post as a nudge and fixed all my regex answers accordingly.

Comment: The vast majority of the time regex questions are so domain-specific as to be completely worthless to anyone other than the OP.  There are of course exceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/match-a-pattern-except-in-three-situations-s1-s2-s3

Comment: we need regex.stackexchange.com !

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A part of a solution might be by using/promoting a jsbin-like environment such as http://www.regexr.com/ It could even be an extension to SO...

This way the authors of answers do not need to explain the basics of regex again and again and can focus on explaining the key to the question.

Comment: That's a great idea!

Comment: I guess it depends what are perceived as the basics. A lot of people already provide a link to an external resource, seemingly as justification for a very terse answer.

Comment: Using regexr or similar site does not relieve you from answering, it makes it *easier* to write a good answer.

Comment: A big problem with regexr is that regexes are environment specific (`\A` vs `^` vs `/s` and `/m` for example). regexr seems to paper over these sharp edges by pretending that pretending that "regex" on its own is meaningful when we all know that "Perl regex", "Ruby regex", "C# regex", ... are all different things. regexr.com can also go down or become unavailable.

Comment: I formed a question over at SR.SE, lets see if something better than regexer is around: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/regluar-expression-tool-like-sqlfiddle

Comment: @muistooshort - Yes, that is why I prefer a solution that is embedded into SO. But that is up to stack exchange to decide. I have no personal preference.

Comment: I seem to remember a similar discussion about using jsfiddle.net in answers, I can't find it right now though. I think the consensus was that things like jsfiddle.net and jsbin.com are great for *supporting* an answer but the answer should be able to stand on its own.

Comment: http://www.regexr.com/ is awesome.

Comment: @muistooshort yes, my point exactly. I consider using such a tool a support for both novice OP's who have a hard time understanding the basics and a tool for people who answer allowing them to concentrate on answering the question while providing greater accessibility to the answer without spending too much time.

Comment: The question over at Software Recommendations brought up Regex Planet http://www.regexplanet.com/ which seems like its covering far more ground than regexer and has some nice features. Unfortunately it seems like not all engines are up all the time.

Comment: I like http://regex101.com

Answer (score 11):

[regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com) is the way to go.

I always create a solution there, then permalink it and copy paste the explanation in the answer with a link back to the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I would think the easiest thing to do is to answer the question yourself. Explain it thoroughly and provide some references (to things that are honestly easily google-able, but not so easily understood.) I haven't been around long, but I've been around long enough to know that if you're unsatisfied with the quality of an answer, submit your own.