# Would it be feasible to add a regex snippet tool?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, editor

I really enjoy having the code snippet tool for browser languages. However, I think it would be nice if that was expanded to have it work for regular expressions.

There are a couple that I would think it would be nice to be modeled on:

http://regexper.com/ -- A nice visual way to see what the regex will do

http://www.regexr.com/ -- A nice way to test input and find matches.

Comment: I like https://regex101.com/, which supports PCRE, JS and Python flavours

Comment: Do you think that will drain the swamp at [tag:regex]?

Comment: @Deduplicator im not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Deduplicator: The phrase is a derivation from what’s supposedly an old southern expression: “When you’re up to your ass in gnats and alligators, it’s easy to forget that the initial objective was to drain the swamp.” It means that when you’re working toward a long-term goal (draining the swamp), your time and energy can be eaten up by urgent, daily tasks (slaying alligators) that don’t necessarily aid you in achieving more important future objectives.

Comment: I don't think it's feasible with the number of languages and implementations (not mentioning version differences).

Comment: Seealso: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255405/563088

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300936/1830736 (shameless plug :)

Answer (score 28):

Very often answers linking to one of the popular online tools are the bad answers ignoring the specificity of the question.

There are too many differences between

- flavors
- implementations (and bugs)
- API (yes, it's often about the functions you might use to get to the goal, not just the expression)

And everything changes with the versions.

I think this would mainly help answering the trivial or already answered questions and decrease the quality of answers to questions supposing a specific expertise.

My opinion is that the effort (moderation and tools) should rather target the too often missing mentions of the specificity (language, tools) and of a minimal test set. This would also help sort the so many regex questions that are, in fact, XY problems.

Comment: Completely agreed. To add - it is also pretty expensive to add (and maintain) for multiple languages/systems together. The gain, as Denys explains is not very big since most RegExp questions I see are either not solved by this ("deep" questions), bad and too specific, or specific to an API.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this one, made with the JS snippet feature. You can use this on any answers you want without attribution. Just add the pre-filled content to the `//Edit Here` section and have fun!

```js
"use strict";

var expression_elm = document.getElementById("expression");
var flags_elm = document.getElementById("flags");
var data_elm = document.getElementById("data");
var output_elm = document.getElementById("out");

//Edit here!
expression_elm.value = "";
flags_elm.value = "";
data_elm.value = "";

function set_output(content) {
  output_elm.innerHTML = content;
}

function group_element(content, g) {
  return '<span class="group-' + g + '" title="Group ' + g + '">' + content + '</span>';
}

function in_range(range, n) {
  return n >= range[0] && n < range[1];
}

function update_match(regex, flags, subject) {
  var characters = subject.split("");
  var groups = new RegExp(regex, flags).exec(subject);

  if (groups !== null) {
    var ranges = [];
    var current_index = 0;
    for (var i = 0, length = groups.length; i < length; i++) {
      var group = groups[i];
      var start = subject.indexOf(group, current_index);
      var end = start + group.length;
      if (i > 0) current_index = end;
      ranges.push([start, end]);
    }

    for (var i = 0, length = characters.length; i < length; i++) {
      var new_char = characters[i];
      for (var j = ranges.length - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
        if (in_range(ranges[j], i)) {
          new_char = group_element(new_char, j);
        }
      }
      characters[i] = new_char;
    }

    set_output(characters.join(""));
  }
}

function on_change() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    update_match(expression_elm.value, flags_elm.value, data_elm.value);
  }, 50);
}

expression_elm.onkeypress = on_change;
data_elm.onkeypress = on_change;
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.group-0 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.group-1,
.group-4,
.group-7 {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3333);
}
.group-2,
.group-5,
.group-8 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3333);
}
.group-3,
.group-6,
.group-9 {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3333);
}
```

```html
<label for="expression">Regular Expression:</label>
<input id="expression" type="text">
<label for="flags">Flags:</label>
<input id="flags" type="text">
<br>
<label for="data">Test Data:</label>
<textarea id="data" type="text"></textarea>
<br>Result:
<br>
<div id="out"></div>
```

(Hover the colored blocks to see which group they are)

If anyone has any improvements to make, feel free to edit this answer.

Comment: That only works for Javascript though, not PCRE or Java.

Comment: @remus Of course. It would be rather unfeasible add all flavors of regexes.

Comment: yeah, but why go to all the effort just to do it for JavaScript?

Comment: @remus It took me just 30 minutes to do this. It can still be used for simpler expressions on most flavours.

Comment: @Kroltan the infeasibility to do it for all regex flavors is *why* this is not a very good idea.